# Anchor Tag is Clickable Across Width of Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a small app and have found a strange bug. I am currently using anchor tags to represent buttons in my app, I could change these to actual buttons instead, but I've decided to stick with anchors for now.

However, I've noticed that the anchor tags are clickable across the entire width of the screen. Could someone please point out why this is occurring? I am assuming it is something wrong with my CSS.

Please see below for an example.

```css
#commentList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
}

#commentList li a {
  width: 364px; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6; 
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="commentList">
  <li onclick=functionA() title="Activate function A."><a href="#" >Function A</a></li>
  <li onclick=functionB() title="Activate function B."><a href="#" >Function B</a></li>
  <li onclick=functionC() title="Activate function B."><a href="#" >Function C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `onclick=functionA()` is on the `li` tag, not on the anchor tag, and the `li`s span the whole width since they are block elements without a `width` setting.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue:

Change:

```
#commentList li a {
      width: 364px; 
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6; 
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      display: block;    
    }
```

To:

```
#commentList li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6; 
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      display: block;    
    }

 #commentList li {
      width: 364px;   
    }
```

The width is being applied to the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>`. You can make it so the width of the `<li>` is still `346px` and still have the `<a>` tag work correctly within it.

See the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d4g8f59h/

Answer (score 0):

On the `a` tag, instead of `display: block;` do `display: inline-block;`